# Handling NSRange In UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, nsrange

I'm having a bit of an issue with `NSRange`. I have a `CommentViewController` which works but I'm trying to have a `tapGesture` and change the the color of the text right after the **@**, like a twitter mention. For some reason, in some of the cells, all of the text changes color as opposed to just the mention. Here's the code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:message[@"text"]];

NSArray *words=[message[@"text"] componentsSeparatedByString:@""];

for (NSString *word in words) {
     if ([word hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
            NSRange range=[message[@"text"] rangeOfString:word];
            [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];
     }
}
[cell.bodyLabel setAttributedText:string];
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I include a gesture to the colored portion?

Comment: you want change the text color . i mean ex : iiiiii@gmail you cange the gmail color.

Comment: I would like to change "@gmail" - yes!

Comment: NSArray *words=[message[@"text"] componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
 to     NSArray *words=[message[@"text"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; Space Missing there

Comment: @HalesEnchanted check my answer.

Comment: @HalesEnchanted     ?

Comment: I had a space, no change :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message[@"text"]];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(@[A-Za-z0-9]*)" options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,message[@"text"].length);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:message[@"text"] options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:subStringRange];
}];

cell.bodyLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. For some reason, if the strFirst starts with the @ gmail for example, the whole text is still red. If I put some text before it like i.e: 'haha @gmail' - it works. What could it be?

Comment: Can you put whole input so i can understand. if `@ gmail` means if space exist then also you want gmail come with red? is that you want?

Comment: I have the code as you do :) The issue is when the @ begins the sentence, it doesn't work. Here's a photo: http://i.imgur.com/URTgMIJ.png

Comment: It is working my side properly you can check here, http://i.stack.imgur.com/J5HNF.png. Have you replace whole code with my one.

Comment: Soo weird. Could it be because it is a cell / indexpath?

Comment: Can you update the question with code that you have put in your code from my answer.

Comment: I think you have put space between this reg exp `[A-Za-z0-9]` check that, because this doesn't contain space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117031/discussion-between-halesenchanted-and-nirav).

Comment: Happy to help...:)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
   NSArray *words=[message[@"text"] componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
```

With

```
    NSArray *words=[message[@"text"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

You should separate component by white space as you separating words not letters!!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *message = @"hello@gmail.com";

NSRange initialRange = [message rangeOfString:@"@"];
NSRange endRange = [message rangeOfString:@"."];
NSUInteger length = endRange.location - initialRange.location;
NSRange markupRange = NSMakeRange(initialRange.location, length);
NSMutableAttributedString * attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:message];
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:markupRange];

[cell.bodyLabel setAttributedText:attString];
```

[image]

This is fairly rough, and I would recommend adding some conditional checks to make sure you don't get any crashes for things like the . before the @, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

plz try this

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message[@"text"]];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(@[A-Za-z0-9]*)" options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSArray *a = [message[@"text"]componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (NSString *str in a) 
{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,str.length);

    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:str options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

        NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:subStringRange];
    }];
    label.attributedText = attributedString;
}
```

Comment: This makes everything red! How come?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. For the most part, I think it was an issue with the regex! Here's my final code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strFirst];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor darkGrayColor] range:(NSRange){0, strFirst.length}];
UIColor *mentionColor = [UIColor hx_colorWithHexRGBAString:@"2cb8f6"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[#@](\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:strFirst options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, strFirst.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
  //  NSString *word = [strFirst substringWithRange:wordRange];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                             value: mentionColor
                             range:wordRange];
}
cell.bodyLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```